# Error message when trying to knit R markdown to word document

Tags: r

I am working in an  R Markdown file. All the codes are run properly and the plot is generated as I want. But, when try to knit the file to a word document I get an error message.

2 questions: How to sort this error?
Is there a better way to export plots to word with good size and clear words.

Details:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Data called SR_STATS

```
read_excel('E:\\MY PROJECTS\\STRESS RADIOGRAPHS\\SR_STATS.xlsx')

PMID    Year    Ligament    Time_Period
3958018 1986    ACL Jan 1983 – Dec 1992
3685366 1987    ACL Jan 1983 – Dec 1992
2229106 1990    ACL Jan 1983 – Dec 1992
2002074 1991    ACL Jan 1983 – Dec 1992
```

First code:

```
FINALSR <- SR_STATS
FINALSR$Ligament <- factor(FINALSR$Ligament,
                           levels = c("Multiligament","Valgus","Varus","PCL","ACL"))
```

Second code:

```
ggplot(data = FINALSR) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Time_Period, fill = Ligament))
```

The plot is generated then when I try to knit the r markdown file to a word document, I get this error message.

> Error in eval (expr, envir, enclos) : object ‘SR_STATS’ not found
> Calls: < Anonymus> ……withvisible eval_user_handlers -> eval  -> eval

I read options on stack overflow but none of them worked

I tried setting the working directory. All my files are in the same folder

There is not eval=false to remove in my R markdown file

I tried both:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE)
```

Comment: Your code example does not assign the result from `read_excel` to any variable. It is also possible that the variable `SR_STATS` exists in your environment when you run code in the console, but is not assigned by the code in your RMarkdown file.

Comment: SR_STATS is not a variable, it is the name of the data frame. FINALSR is the new name for the data after rearranged the variable Ligament

Comment: The name of a data frame is a variable name. The question stands: does your (real) code assign the result from `read_excel` to the variable `SR_STATS` or not?

Comment: Apologies, I am very new to R. How do I assign the results from read_excel to the variable SR_STATS. What I posted is the real code I used

Comment: You need to do this: `SR_STATS <- read_excel('E:\\MY PROJECTS\\STRESS RADIOGRAPHS\\SR_STATS.xlsx')`. Otherwise the data frame `SR_STATS` with the data from the Excel file will not exist. Does that help with the error?

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, it has helped with the error. But there is another thing now, half of the title that I added for the plot is missing when it is on the word document. Any idea how to sort that?

Comment: Best to open a new question for new questions. Although that sounds like something you could solve with some trial and error.